# reload or refresh images once a variable has been change in another image file?

Tags: php, ajax, reload

I have a form that lets a user select a list of courses, upon selection the value equals a course code 111 for instance. I can update a variable in a php graph generating file through AJAX with this selection.... the trouble is that i need to refresh or reload these images dynamically. i display the images like so;

```
<?php
for ($i = 1; $i < 39; $i++)
{
    $sqlquestion = 'SELECT Question FROM tquestion WHERE QuestionID = '.$i.'';
    $questiontext = mysql_query($sqlquestion,$odbc) or die ("can not run query");
    $q = mysql_fetch_row($questiontext);  
?>
    <div id="bars"><img src="bars.php?graph=<?php echo $i;?>"></div>
<?php
}
```

this loop provides me with 38 graphs (one for each question from a survey)

I am stuck how to redisplay these graphs once the variable has been changed.

I hope I've made sence any help would be greatly appreciated :)
Thanks

Comment: you should use jquery or javascript to change "src" attribute  of "img" html element after ajax request success.

Comment: not sure id quite know how to code that... could you guide me in the right direction please? ; thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

After your ajax request success add code below at the end of your success function.

```
$('#bars img').attr("src", "path/to/new/image.jpg"); // replace path with your image path
```

if you use jQuery ajax this code should be at end of success function, as below

```
$.ajax({

success: function(){
         // but the code at end of this function 
},
});
```

I hope this help